# How can I get swimming pool length from the HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

[image: screenshotImage]

I can get swimming distance data and swimming stroke count data..
But I can't get swimming pool length data..
How can I get the swimming pool length?

```swift
...
guard let distance = workout.statistics(for: .init(.distanceSwimming)),
      let meter = distance.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter()),
      let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .swimmingStrokeCount)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From here...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyswimmingstrokestyle

It looks like there is a key `HKMetadataKeyLapLength` that would be the pool length.

Comment: thanks.. I tried HKMetadataKeyLapLength before..but it return nil ... :(

Comment: It would have to be set by the app that the user uses when tracking their swimming.

Comment: @Hoody Perhaps the app uses their custom metadata key then. Try printing out the whole metadata dictionary.

Comment: I just printed "print(sample.metadata)".  ...  only HKSwimmingStrokeStyle exist.. Optional(["HKSwimmingStrokeStyle": 1])

Comment: Looks like that value isn't set for the data you're lookin at then.